# Why does the quantum walk operator only have two eigenvectors?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-walks, hamiltonian

In [Child's paper on the relationship between discrete and continuous quantum walks](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0312), he makes the following claim.

[image]

Although he provides a proof after this:

[image]

I don't understand how the walk operator must have only two eigenvectors. To compute $\left | \mu \right >$ using $\left | \mu_\pm \right > = \frac{1 - e^{\pm i acos \lambda} S}{\sqrt{2(1 - \lambda^2)}}T \left | \lambda \right >$, which eigenvectors, $\left | \lambda \right >$ of $\hat{H}$ would we use?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it claim that it *only* has two eigenvalues, or does it just claim that two of the eigenvalues have these values... (leaving open the possibility of other eigenvalues, which will probably turn out to be irrelevant to the evolution)

Comment: @DaftWullie Oh, I completely misinterpreted that. I don’t think it ever mentions these being the only eigenvectors. 

But I’m not sure how we would know which eigenvectors are relevant to the evolution. I’ll read a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Basically, you only need the set of eigenvectors that have an overlap with the initial state. So, if you can find some set of eigenvectors, and show that your initial state can be completely decomposed in terms of them, you're done!